# PHP SQL JOIN Avoid ID Duplicates

Tags: php, sql

I am using this code:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
      JOIN Table2 USING(venue_id)
      WHERE table2.location = '$MyVariable'
```

Then to count the number of records return:

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "$num_rows";
```

It works great but venue_id in Table1 has lots of entries and I only want it to get one per venue_id

How can I make it so it only returns 1 venue_id instance?

Comment: GROUP by solves you problem? if not i have another idea.

Comment: just my idea hope it will work: SELECT COUNT(Table1.venue_id) as venue_id_count FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 USING(venue_id) WHERE table2.location = '$MyVariable'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` clause,

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
JOIN Table2 USING(venue_id)
WHERE table2.location = '$MyVariable'
GROUP BY `Table1`.`venue_id`
```